# ReactJS proxy URL for localhost API in PROD when bundling with Spring Boot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, frontend, backend

I'm trying to bundle ReactJS and Spring Boot API together and build one fat jar. In every tutorial I read, I'm told to put the localhost API URL as a proxy in package.json of the React app like below.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

As I obviously don't have PROD deployment experience with this, is this the way to go when you are deploying in PROD? Else, please guide me in the right direction. I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Also, any cons in doing so in a medium sized project with two developers? Appreciate any input.

Comment: did you took a looked at my answer?

Comment: Yes I just did. Replied to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "proxy" field should only be used in development environment when the Webpack dev server is first in line(to enable the Hot-Reload feature)
Here is a guide from 2018:
[spring + react guide](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/19/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot)

regardless there are two main way of hosting the react app:

1. inside the spring boot Jar a static resource(you can use frontend-maven-plugin to run yarn/ npm again see the guide),
   the advantages of this method is security, you don't need CORS enabled to serve the page.
   the disadvantages is convenient this solution require more code, also the spring boot server handles UI serving to the client that requires extra calls to the server(spring first approach)
2. the other option is to host it in a hosting service like amazon S3 and then it will be hosted not in spring but in s3 and will be the first in line(UI first approach), you will need to enable CORS in spring boot app, but this is a more continent solution.

ps. I would read some guides first, it would help you with general understanding

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer Roie. Clears lots of things for me. In the first way of doing it, how would you define the URL for the fetch requests if both the UI and the backend is bundled together in deployment?
Also, thanks for the link to the tutorial.

Comment: @suharsha because spring is the first in line any controller that you will add will be in priority over the UI, spring first is trying to match path to a controller and only if non is found go to static by default....

Comment: I think you did not get my question. If I'm doing a fetch request in my React app to a resource in my Spring Boot backend (which are bundled together), what is the URL for the backend? As an example, will it be localhost/api/get?

Comment: don't use the initial part of the URL, this is in the example, but 
hostname/api/get -> fetch(api/get) should be enough  it will resolve the hostname automatically

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you so much Roie for the clarifications. Much appreaciated :)